# Cant fetch data from an endpoint in react using fetch()

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

NO error and not prinitng anything on console

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Component } from 'react';
import React from 'react';
import { CircularProgressbar, buildStyles } from 'react-circular-progressbar';
import 'react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const percentage = 70;

class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: [],
      DataisLoaded: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8081', {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors',
    })
      .then((response) => {
        var data = response.json();
        return data;
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    /*fetch(
"http://localhost:8081")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => {
            this.setState({
                items: json,
                DataisLoaded: true
            });
        })*/
  }

  render() {
    /*useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8081')
         .then((response) => console.log(response));
       }, []);*/
    const { items, DataisLoaded } = this.state;
    //var pob = JSON.stringify(items);

    //if (!DataisLoaded) return <div>
    //  <h1> Loading Your Dashboard.... </h1> </div> ;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className='navbar'>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon='fa-solid fa-right-from-bracket' />
          <button className='btn btn-light logout'>Logout </button>
        </div>

        <div className='sidebar tex-center align-items-center'>
          <h2>Hello!</h2>

          <h1 className='name px-5 py-8'>{items.name}</h1>

          <div className='roundrec'>
            <h6> Current Weight - 70kg </h6>
            <h6> Target Weight - 60kg</h6>
          </div>

          <div className='cald'>
            <h5> Todays Calorie </h5>
            <h5 className='calo-text'> 1390 cal </h5>
            <CircularProgressbar
              value={percentage}
              text={`${percentage}%`}
              styles={buildStyles({
                textColor: 'red',
                pathColor: 'red',
              })}
            />
            ;
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='maincontent'>
          <div className='todaysfoodtext'>
            <h1>Add Todays Food</h1>
          </div>
          <div className='todaysfoodsearch'>
            <h3>Todays Food</h3>
          </div>
          <div className='quantity'>
            <h3>Quantity</h3>
          </div>
          <div className='add'>
            <h3>Add</h3>
          </div>

          <div className='foodconsumedbox'>
            <h7>Food consumed</h7>
            <div className='food1'>
              <h8>Dosa x2</h8>
            </div>
            <div className='food2'>
              <h8>Dosa x2</h8>
            </div>
            <div className='food3'>
              <h8>Dosa x2</h8>
            </div>
            <div className='food4'>
              <h8>Dosa x2</h8>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='carbohydrates'>
            <CircularProgressbar
              value={percentage}
              text={`${percentage}%`}
              styles={buildStyles({
                textColor: 'white',
                pathColor: 'white',
              })}
            />
            <h4>carbohydarates</h4>
          </div>

          <div className='protiens'>
            <CircularProgressbar
              value={percentage}
              text={`${percentage}%`}
              styles={buildStyles({
                textColor: 'white',
                pathColor: 'white',
              })}
            />
            <h4>protiens</h4>
          </div>

          {/*<div className="nutrients">
          <CircularProgressbar value={percentage} text={`${percentage}%`}      styles={buildStyles({
              textColor: "white",
              pathColor: "white",
              
            })} />
          <h4>nutrients</h4>
          </div>*/}

          <div className='fats'>
            <CircularProgressbar
              value={percentage}
              text={`${percentage}%`}
              styles={buildStyles({
                textColor: 'white',
                pathColor: 'white',
              })}
            />
            <h4>fats</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: Can you post your server-side code handling the `GET` request?

Answer (score 0):

It might be case that your API endpoint not returning anything, check your API in postman first, is it working fine ?

Comment: your code seems to be fine.